# Specify PDF filename using Shine PDF plugin

Tags: add-on

I'm using [Shine PDF](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/shine-pdf)to convert an EE template to pdf, and I need to figure out how to specify the file name when the pdf is downloaded (it defaults to mpdf.pdf). The docs seem to imply that the  tag is used, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

I've tried contacting Shine about it via email and twitter and gotten no response.
Has anyone who has used Shine PDF successfully specified the document title? Or is anyone familiar enough with the mpdf library to suggest how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify the title by using a regular  HTML tag pair:

```
{exp:shine_pdf:make channel="my_channel"}
    <title>My PDF Title</title>
    ...
{/exp:shine_pdf:make}
```